# Basic Tic Tac Toe in Java without arrays

Tags: java, loops, methods, tic-tac-toe

I am currently writing a basic Java program for a tic tac toe board. I am trying to build this without arrays, but almost every online help uses them. I have much of the code written, but I am hitting a wall on creating a method to print the updated board with the characters (X or O) in the board. I am also supposed to create a game that plays against the computer, but does not have to be anything other than random. I know I can use Math.random to select the computer move, but I am not certain how to construct using the code I have. The missing pieces are:

- After a valid input is received the symbol is placed and the board is printed to the console
  -computer randomly placing its ‘O’ on a non-occupied field and include checking for a winner
  -create a game loop that continues until there is a winner

import java.util.Scanner;

//Heather Richards author

public class Assignment3TicTacToe {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Create scanner
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Input loop
            input: while (true) {
            System.out.print("Please enter your move: "); String move = input.next();

    //Checking for correct input
            if (move.length() == 2) {
                char row = move.charAt(0);
                int number = Character.getNumericValue(move.charAt(1)); 

                if (((row == 'a') || (row == 'b') || (row == 'c'))
                        && ((number == 1) || (number == 2) || (number == 3))) {



                } else {
                    System.out.println("Please only enter the right code (a1,...) for the play!");
                    }


            }
    //Variables declared to hold spaces on the board
    char a1 = ' ';
    char a2 = ' ';
    char a3 = ' ';
    char b1 = ' ';
    char b2 = ' ';
    char b3 = ' ';
    char c1 = ' ';
    char c2 = ' ';
    char c3 = ' ';

    // Method called to print updated game board
    public static String gameGrid(char a1, char a2,char a3, char b1, char b2, char b3, char c1, char c2, char c3){  

    // Prompt user to play game and enter a position
    System.out.println( "Welcome to Tic-Tac-Toe. Please enter your first move: ");


    // Create game grid
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("    1    2    3  ");
    System.out.println(" |----|----|----|");
    System.out.println("A|   " + a1 + "|   " + a2 + "|   " + a3 + "|   ");
    System.out.println(" |____|____|____|");
    System.out.println("B|   " + b1 + "|   " + b2 + "|   " + b3 + "|   ");
    System.out.println(" |____|____|____|");
    System.out.println("C|   " + c1 + "|   " + c2 + "|   " + c3 + "|   ");
    System.out.println(" |____|____|____|");




    //Checking to see if position on board is empty, entering X for human interaction
        switch (row) { 
        case 'a':
            switch (number) { 
            case 1:
                if (a1 == ' ') {
                    a1 = 'X';
                    break input; 
                } else
                    System.out.println("This field is already taken, choose another!"); 
                break;
            case 2:
                if (a2 == ' ') {
                    a2 = 'X';
                    break input;
                }
                else
                    System.out.println("This field is already taken, choose another!"); 
                break;
            case 3:
                if (a3 == ' ') {
                    a3 = 'X';
                    break input; 
                } else{
                    System.out.println("This field is already taken, choose another!");
                break;
                }

            case 4:
                if (b1 == ' ') {
                    b1 = 'X';
                    break input; 
                } else
                    System.out.println("This field is already taken, choose another!"); 
                break;
            case 5:
                if (b2 == ' ') {
                    b2 = 'X';
                    break input;
                }
                else
                    System.out.println("This field is already taken, choose another!"); 
                break;
            case 6:
                if (b3 == ' ') {
                    b3 = 'X';
                    break input; 
                } else
                    System.out.println("This field is already taken, choose another!"); 
                break;

            case 7:
                if (c1 == ' ') {
                    c1 = 'X';
                    break input;
                } else
                    System.out.println("This field is already taken, choose another!"); 
                break;
            case 8:
                if (c2 == ' ') {
                    c2 = 'X';
                    break input;

                }else
                    System.out.println("This field is already taken, choose another!"); 
                break;
            case 9:
                if (c3 == ' ') {
                    c3 = 'X';
                    break input;
                } else
                    System.out.println("This field is already taken, choose another!"); 
                break;
            }
            break;



}
    }
}
```

}
        }

Thanks for your help!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: "I am trying to build this without arrays" - um, why?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to familiarize yourself with the Stack Overflow [help file](http://stackoverflow.com/help), which will help you understand what kinds of questions are appropriate for this site. This site is intended to help you obtain answers to *specific programming questions*, as opposed to providing tutorial, design or code review assistance. HINT: Choose just one of the questions you asked and provide only the relevant bits of code.

Comment: First you need to make a method for printing the board, then you need to make a copy of your switch, and one copy use it to make the move, and the other to check if the space is available. then you can do this in a loop:print, checkmove,domove, repeat until no more moves are available (check move returns false for all moves). I would do the code, but im at work hehe.

Comment: Maybe it is time to learn multidimensional arrays...it will make you stronger!

Comment: Please don't try to do this with 9 separate variables.  You will drive yourself crazy, and you won't learn anything useful except that you'll learn why it's important to know how to use arrays.

Comment: So use [lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) instead of arrays?

Comment: That is the assignment. We haven't learned arrays yet. I am trying to learn on my own, but this was the task set to me, so....

Comment: luisluix, you are spot on for what I am trying to accomplish. But my method is misbehaving (tried a few different ones). I think I need this to be public static void, because I am not returning anything, right? As far as the separate variables, ajb, unfortunately, this was the beginning code given by the instructor, the separate variables. David Conrad, I will look into lists....